# 2D Matrix problem

Tags: algorithms

Given a N*N matrix (1 indexed) which is initially zero.
That is all its row and column are zero.

Now I have to transform it to new matrix being entered in minimum number of moves where I can perform only one kind of operation on the matrix.The operation is as follow : 
I can take K,Upper,Down,Left,Right and change value to K at all (i , j) such that (Upper ≤ i ≤ Down and Left ≤ j ≤ Right).
The (i, j) is the value at the ith row and the jth columm.

Main point is that if a (i,j) position is changed several time, it final value is corresponding to the last time it is changed.

How to do it in effective manner?

Example :

Given a 4 * 4 matrix

0 0 0 0

1 5 1 0

1 5 1 0

1 5 1 0

It can be achieved in 2 moves

1 2 4 1 3

5 2 4 2 2

Meaning first change the value to 1 from (2,1) to (4,3) and then change value to 5 from (2,2) to (4,2).

Comment: A direct dynamic programming solution won't work, consider the table $\begin {bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ , no direct recursion of the problem itself will find this in polytime (not saying other recursions couldn't, just that a direct one won't).  Here is a discussion of the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431342/algorithm-to-find-the-optimal-way-of-covering-a-plane-with-colored-rectangles

Comment: What is the best possible method to do it then.?which provide result nearest to most effective solution